# Update Symfony-cli with symfony 5.4 - ARM64

Tags: symfony5, symfony-cli

Symfony-cli update

Before i had this old version.

```
 ## Symfony-cli
RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony-cli update

Go to DockerFile apache or nginx

```
## Symfony-cli
RUN wget -c https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/releases/download/v5.4.1/symfony-cli_linux_arm64.tar.gz && tar -xf symfony-cli_linux_arm64.tar.gz  && chmod +x symfony && mv symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```